# Insert dynamically user comments into a chart [Highcharts]

Tags: javascript, highcharts, react-highcharts

I need to be able user insert user comments on the chart dynamically way. It means, the user will view the chart and will decide to make a comment on the chart or not.
P.S.: The user could make one or more comments anywhere on the chart.

I'm using Highcharts JS with ReactJS.
And I saw this functionality in Highcharts Stock and would like to know if it's possible to make it with Highcharts JS.

Comment: This functionality is available only on the Highcharts Stock product. Highcharts Stock uses a Highcharts as a core, so you should be able to render some basic charts using it.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.